# How to read XML node's value in InstallScript

Tags: xml, dom, installshield, installscript, installscript-msi

I have following XML file.

```
<Configuration>
    <Config1 connection="SQL">SampleData<Config1>
</Configuration>
```

I want to read the value "SampleData" of node Config1 in InstallScript function. I tried properties text, value, nodevalue. But none of it worked. I can read attribute connection's value. But how I can read node's value "SampleData"?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: No. I'm using SingleSuite installer of InstallShield. It doesn't have the functionality of SystemSearch or XML search. So I'm writing CustomAction code to read/write XML node value.

Comment: OK, you saw the github link? Perhaps it works.

Answer (score 0):

***Help Documentation***: Maybe try this help file documentation:

- [Searching for XML Data](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/XML-AppSearch.htm)
- [Modifying XML Files](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/ModifyingXMLFileChanges.htm)

  - [Using XPath Expressions to Find XML Data in an XML File](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/XML-XPath.htm)
- [XML File Changes View](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/XMLFileChangesView.htm)
- [Using Windows Installer Properties to Dynamically Modify XML Files](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/XML-MSIProps.htm)

There are several other places in the help file that XML issues are discussed, but that should get you going.

---

***Installscript***: I suppose you could go Installscript on it. I would not recommend it. I don't have any samples for you, but [pillaging github.com giveth the following](https://github.com/ramguptha/temp/blob/9d8ed1ef3d0267f71d72ca792b96f174b6ee954f/installer/AmWebMsi/Script%20Files/ReadXmlValueFromFile.rul). No idea if it works, but maybe give it a go. No guarantees at all - at your own risk.

---

***Some Further Links***:

- [Adding Support for XML Encoding Options](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/SettingsXML-Encoding.htm)
- [Advanced Tab for an XML File](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/XML-AdvancedXMLFile.htm)